# Google Map isn't show on Kendo Popup Editor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I am working on the user information popup window with Kendo ASP.NET. The popup also has tabs which are created with `@Html.Kendo().TabStrip()`.

So far, displaying and entering data works fine. But, I'm having trouble with adding a map into the popup editor.

This is sample popup. There are street name, street number, etc. Although Google Map doesn't interact with data yet, I wanted it display correctly.

Location.cshtml:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("tabstripLocationPopup")
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("Location")
              .Selected(true)
              .LoadContentFrom("", "")
              .Content(@<text>
<div id="GeoLocation" class="tab" style="overflow: auto; height: 90%;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend accesskey="I">Identification</legend>
        <table border="0" style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid black;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lat, "Latitude")
                        </td>
                        <td class="editor">
                            @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(model => model.Lat).Name("Lat")
                        </td>

                        <td class="label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Long, "Longitude")
                        </td>
                        <td class="editor">
                            @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(model => model.Long).Name("Long")
                        </td>
                    <tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>
</div>
    </text>);

          })
    )
```

I added script to index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPICode&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
</script>
```

If I add this code to index.cshtml file, then a map display correctly.

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:200px"></div>
</body>
```

However, I want it to be displayed inside of popup (Location.cshtml).

The only way that I make it show is add button in Javascript and initialize map when button was clicked.

Please guide me if I missed something here.

Comment: How come there's no closing tag for your `<div>` inside of the TabStrip's Content?

Comment: ataravati, there is closing tag for <div>. I just missed it when I copied my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this dojo that I have set up

[Google Maps on pop up](http://dojo.telerik.com/EVaMA)

to highlight what I have done.

**Note: You will need to add your API Key and authorise the site in your API Dev console for the map to be shown otherwise you will get an Unauthorised or Invalid Key message being shown**

I used one of Telerik's own demos and then added the following bits:

```
editable: {
               mode: "popup",
               template: kendo.template($("#editor").html())
          }, 
edit: function(e){ initialize()}
```

then added this sample template script for the pop up window. Removing everything else just to keep it simple

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div id="GeoLocation" class="tab" style="overflow: auto;width:300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>
</script>
```

Then just using your initialize script like so:

```
   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
                       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                       zoom: 8,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                     };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("GeoLocation"),
        mapOptions);
  }
```

All I had to do is move where this code is being called. From the usual **OnLoad** that google usually demo's to the edit function of the grid. 
So when the pop up window is shown this will get fired off before the window is shown and initialize it to what ever you need it too.

if you need any further help let me know.

Comment: I appreciate your answers. First, I have my own API key but didn't want to share on this post. So this isn't problem because it is working on single html file that I created for test purpose; however, not on kendo popup.

Comment: I understand not sharing the api key as I tested the code using my api key and removed it from the dojo. If you copy and pasted your api key into the dojo did it work as expected?  (or just copy and paste the code into a new dojo and then you can make sure it works). For your scenario I would suggest you create an editor template for the grid and then you can add on the custom code. if you need an example I can add it to my answer for you.

Comment: Second, in some how, event function caused hiccups auto-resizing popup windows. So I am using method to call popup editor `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ICWeb.Models.GeoLocation>().Name("GeoLocation").Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))`
With your suggestion, I added `.Events(e => e.Edit("initialize"))` now popup window displays Google Map. Thanks!

Comment: You commented before I posted my comment above. When I pasted my API key to dojo, map works. I would like to learn what you mentioned in your comment. Would you provide an example for me?

Comment: So do you still need an example or have you now fixed your issue? If you have now resolved your issue and my answer did help please feel free to mark it as the answer. If there is anything else that you need adding let me know and I will update the answer.